# Align nested SVGs horizontally

Tags: svg

I'd like to have two nested SVGs align horizontally (side-by-side). However the default behavior seems to be that they collapse and overlap, such that only the red SVG is visible, along with the rest of the parent SVG.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

```
<svg width="80" height="40" style="background-color:skyblue">
  <svg width="40" height="40">
    <path d="M0,0 h40 v40 h-40 v-40 z" fill="green"/>
  </svg>
  <svg width="40" height="40">
    <path d="M0,0 h40 v40 h-40 v-40 z" fill="red"/>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5qjcLpdt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the dimensions above, I'm assuming you want the two square SVG elements to be horizontally aligned atop the parent. Here, x and y coordinates were added to the child elements in order to position them:

```html
    <svg width="80" height="40" style="background-color:skyblue">
      <svg x=0 y=0 width="40" height="40">
        <path d="M0,0 h40 v40 h-40 v-40 z" fill="green"/>
      </svg>
      <svg x=40 y=0 width="40" height="40">
        <path d="M0,0 h40 v40 h-40 v-40 z" fill="red"/>
      </svg>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! You use the term "atop" the parent. I would have thought of them as "within" the parent. Can you comment on the distinction? Ie: is it more correct to think of nested SVGs as layered than contained?